# Stress testing web services - best approach

Tags: c#, web-services, automated-tests, stress-testing

I have several web services I need to create for them some testing mechanism and to use it as a tool for stress testing.

What's the best way to tackle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a tool for the purpose, like [The Grinder](http://grinder.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: In my company they don't like Java, is there a C# framework with the same capabilities?

Comment: Well if you can point it at your WS ... and test it, why bother caring what language the tool is made in ?

Comment: @Yarin Miran, not that I know of. But the use of the word framework may be confusing you a bit. It is a framework, but it comes with a scriptable GUI that you can directly use (requiring only the JVM) to stress test your web services. The scripting (in Jython) is useful if you want to test on ...

Comment: ... the presence of certain conditions or to replay the behavior of a human (not applicable in this case). But you can use it just setting some parameters like URL, amount of threads, how many requests per cycle and so on.

Answer (score 1):

[JMeter](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/) is also a great solution, as is [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/)

I prefer SoapUI due to the extra features you get with test case creation.